# Share iPhone internet to MacBook by lightning (without HotSpot)

Tags: iphone, usb, internet

I am curious can I share my 3G connection from iPhone to MacBook by lightning cable, not using HotSpot (it not always working properly). Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about USB tethering?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using a wireless connection to share your 3G connection, you can still use Personal Hotspot, but with a Lightning cable, according to [Apple's support documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204023).

> **Set up Personal Hotspot**
>
> 1. Go to Settings > Cellular.
> 2. Tap Personal Hotspot, then tap the slider to turn it on.
>
> **Connect to Personal Hotspot with USB**
>
> Make sure that you have the latest version of iTunes on your Mac or PC. Then connect your iPhone or iPad to your computer with the USB cable that came with your device. If you see an alert that says tap "Trust This Computer?" tap Trust.